# how to sync the clock of two computer with each other using c++

Tags: c++, linux, windows, algorithm

I have two computer say A and B. I need to make sure that they are sync to each other vey accurately (in the range of ms). One computer is windows base and the other is Linux. They are connected to each other by Ethernet directly (a cable from one computer is connected to other). I can write C/C++ code for each of them.

How can I make them synch to each other y noting that neither windows nor Linux are real time system and hence you don't know how long would it takes that a packet that you sent over Ethernet is received by other side so you can not compensate for it. Since you need accuracy of ms, this delay is important.

Is there any algorithm that can do this?

is there any function in windows/Linux that can be send to make sure that when you send data via Ethernet, it is passed to other side instantly?

Comment: connect both to an atomic clock!

Comment: Implement the NTP protocol, or just install a NTP server on one and a NTP client on the other.

Comment: @MitchWheat I'm pretty sure he said milliseconds not picoseconds

Comment: But NTP is not accurate enough as the delay in Ethernet is there anyway? Am I wrong?

Comment: @PeterT: see posters next comment! :)

Comment: a good starting point would be e.g. here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_synchronization (how about e.g. [Precision Time Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_Time_Protocol)

Comment: Wikipedia states that over the internet it is up to 10ms exact and on a local ethernet it can be up to 200μs exact. Read the [standard](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc958) to know how exactly it is done.

Comment: @ComicSansMS: Sorry, but that's plain wrong. You can't achieve synchronization better than the _jitter_ in the latency. If I have a precise and stable 1.56734 millisecond latency, I can sync with sub-microsecond accuracy.

Comment: GPS time on both boxes?  I guess that's similar to @MitchWheat 'connect both to atomic clock'.

Comment: @MSalters You are right of course. Sorry for the sloppy word choice.

Answer (score 4):

Syncrhonizing a clock between two machines is not an easy and trivial task.

One known way to do it with a descent accuracy is [Marzullo's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marzullo%27s_algorithm)

Comment: This is generally true, but he said they don't really need that degree of precision.  (He mentionned something on the order of a millisecond, which isn't very precise.)  If both machines are on the same LAN, he can probably get by with simpler methods.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 basic ways to do this some more complicated than others but the all use a basic rule which is based on local clock offset timing. these 3 are RBS, TPSN, and FTSP the common rule looks after any latency across each layer the synchronization schemes have four basic packet delay components: send time, access time, propagation time, and receive time see http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~jain/cse574-06/ftp/time_sync/index.html